# Visualising data dynamically by choosing min and max values for xAxis with Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I' m making web app, where i have two arrays and form to choose from interval from one of them (the array for xAxis). One of the arrays is for xAxis and another one is for yAxis:

```
var array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7];
```

and for y:

```
var arrayY =[2,3,6,5,2,4,6,8,7,5,4,7,9,7,8,6,1,2,3,5,6,7,6,5,4,5,6,7,8,9,7,6,5,4,2,1,3,4,6,7,8,9,7,6,5,4,5,63,7,8,];
```

The demo of my program is here: http://jsfiddle.net/vcpk211c/5/

The chart is working ok, but the problem is when i am choosing from where to where i want to get values for xAxis. When i tab from 0 to 4 for example, i get only 4 values. What i want is when i tab from 0 to 4, to get [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4].
I suppose the problem is in Highcharts code, because only the jQuery code is working ok, but when i add the code for the chart, everything goes wrong. Can you help me with that ??

Comment: Your xAxis category array makes no sense. Why would you have identical x values for your first 6 y values? What exactly are you trying to plot? Do you have an example of expected output?

Comment: ^ agreed.  I can't make any sense of what "[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4]" is supposed to do or look like.

Comment: Because the arrays are from xml file. This xml have measurements of masses and the array for x have those kind of values.Those values are numbers of masses which are repeating.  The xAxis has few arrays and this is one of them. Those few arrays are independent values. For yAxis i have dependent values and i have to make visualisations of independent values for x and dependent values for y.

Comment: So i have to tell the program "Give me from 0 to 4" and i have to get all values from 0 to 4, even those that are repeating."

Comment: And of course i have to get the same number of values for y too. if i get from 0 to 4, those are 28 values. The yAxis have to get 28 values too ...

Comment: What is "y" value? You said x is supposed to be mass. Why would a single mass have multiple "y" values to be plotted with multiple masses? Are each "mass" items supposed to be separate series of data (one for mass = 0, one for mass = 1, etc etc)?

Comment: No, not each mass supposed to be separate series of data. xAxis is array_no of the masses and y are measerments for maximal energies..  If i choose for x: "0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1" (form 0 to 1) (this is array_no), for y i am going to have the first 11 values...  "2,3,6,5,2,4,6,8,7,5,4" and those are maximal energies. That's all. I just have to show how the dependents values (those for y)  dependent from independents values (those for x).

Comment: @Veronica, do you have an example of what this is supposed to looks like? It is not very clear how a single mass can have multiple maximal energies.